# ZF2 DI Setter Injection not working anymore

Tags: model-view-controller, dependency-injection, zend-framework2

I've used this in my module.config.php since early betas:

```php
'di' => array(
    'instance' => array(
        'alias' => array(
            'Model' => 'Application\Model\Application',
        ),
        'Application\Controller\IndexController' => array(
            'parameters' => array(
                'Model' => 'Model',
            )
        ),
    ),
),
```

Having this in indexController:

```php
protected $Model;

public function setModel (\Application\Model\Model $Model)
{
    $this->Model = $Model;
}
```

But it stopped to work since I updated from beta5 to rc2. I cant find the change in the ZF2 code nor documentation.

Answer (score 1):

A security hole was closed that changes the way DI is used for controllers. See:
https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/pull/2005

Answer (score 0):

As @superdweebie mentioned, security hole was closed where Di could instantiate non-controller class.
To continue using controllers from Di you must whitelist them in Di config:

```php
return array(
    'di' => array(
        'allowed_controllers' => array(
            // controllers list goes here
        ),
        //...
    ),
);
```

Also check [this blog post by Marco Pivetta](http://ocramius.github.com/blog/zend-framework-2-controllers-and-dependency-injection-with-zend-di/).
It explains how to use Di and controllers.